# PHP/MYSQL: Slowly iterate through 6k rows and for every row create new records - Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, select, recursion

I'm sorry for stupid question, but I have one of these days, where I feel like the dumbest programmer. I need your help. I'm currently developing with PHP and MYSQL, where I'm like super low skilled and I'm working on inherited project.

I have database table with almost 6k records in it, let's say TABLE_A, and I need to iterate through the records in TABLE A and for every record create two new records in TABLE B where the PK from TABLE_A(Id) is FK in TABLE_B. Nothing special right? So I have one more thing, this is happening, don't blame please, in production DB. So I got a request to run the insertion into table B only for 10 records every 1 second. Furthermore, I have list of Ids which looks like this: 1,2,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,15,16,.. to 6k. So I cannot basically do:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= MAX(id); $i++) {
    //create two new records in TABLE B
}
```

I have spent some time with the research and I need to talk about it with you guys, to come up with some ideas. **I don't want from you the exact solution, but I want to learn how to think about that and how to come up with the solution**. I was thinking about it on my way home. So I just created the algorithm in my head. Here is step-by-step process in my head about what I know and what I will probably use:

1. I know that I can run just 10 inserts per 1 second - so I need to limit the select from TABLE A for just 5 rows in one batch.
2. So I can probably use MySQL syntax: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, for example: `select * from t LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0`
3. This means that I have to store the id of the last record from the previous batch.
4. After finishing current batch, I need to wait for 1 second( I'm think about using PHP method `sleep()`) before starting new batch.
5. I need loop
6. The exact number of rows in TABLE_A is for now unusable
7. The insertion of new records is simple. Focus on the iteration.

So here is something I have on the paper and I'm not quite sure if it is going to work or not, because I really want to learn something from this problem. I will skip the things around, like connect DB,etc and will focus just on the algorithm and will write in some hybrid PHP/Mysql/Pseudo code.

```
$limit=5
$offset=0;

function insert($limit, $offset){
   $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tableA LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
   $stm->execute(array('limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset));
   while($stm->rowCount() > 0){ 
      $data = $stm->fatchAll();
      foreach($data as $row){
         // insert into TABLE_B
      }
      sleep(1);
      $offset +=5;
      $this->insert($limit, $offset);
   }
}
```

I'm not totally sure, if this recursion will work. On paper it looks feasible. But what about performance? It's a problem in this case?

**Maybe the main question is: Am I over thinking this? Do you know about better solution how to do that?**

Thank you for any comments, thoughts, suggestions, ideas and detail descriptions of your procedure how to come up with feasible solution. Probably I should dig more into some algorithm analysis and design. Do you know any good resources?

*(Sorry for grammar mistakes, I'm not a native speaker)*

Comment: you dont need to sorry for bad English ... and it seems like you have tried your best and this is what community suppose to do by op ..

Comment: honestly if it was me I would offline it.. mysqldump the data out pull it down to a local db run the queries en mass then push them all up at once.

Comment: yes I know, probably the best solution in terms of security is to go offline and do it. But I can't do it with production DB.

Comment: you have to also consider the data changing (e.g. what is every 6th row) while you are inserting new records.  Your query on tableA should be based upon records that have a missing relationship with tableB or some other benchmark of how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you have to insert into table B for 10 records per 1 second, but let's assume that this condition can not be changed.

Your sources code are right, however recursion is not necessary here, we should do something like that.

```
limit=5
offset=0

while (itemsA = fetch_from_a(limit, offset)) {
    # you should do a batch insertion here, see MySQL's documentation.
    insert_into_B(itemsA);         
    sleep(1);
    offset += 5;
}

# prototype
# fetch some records from table A, return array of found items 
# or an empty array if nothing was found.
function fetch_from_a(limit, offset);
```

Comment: 1 small enhancement: 
instead of `offset = offset + 5`
write `offset = offset + limit`
to make things more dynamic.